# How can I find an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I use a GUI to create my page, it is saved as a JSON file, then the JSON file is read by a CMS.

**The problem:** I would like to tinker with the objects I created, but the code is super minimized, an I cannot find the object.

To be clear with an example. I create a page with a button named "BUTTON". It exports in a JSON like this:

```
"S":[  
     {  
        "Y":"h",
        "b":1,
        "nm":"BUTTON1",
        "f":"1,0,1,0",
        "c":"FFFFFF,000000",
        "l":"2020,1840,4140,8820",
        "n":"Helvetica",
        "h":192,
        "L":0,
        "i":0,
        "j":1,
        "vj":1,
        "t":"Button",
        "Act":[  
           {  
              "e":"OnClick",
              "s":"\r\ngraphicReplace(\"Public/essai/vue0\");"
           }
        ]
     }
 ]
```

And it displays a button in the CMS. But, if I try something like "alert(S.t);", I get a "ReferenceError: S is not defined".

**What I would like to do**, is find a way to say:
Find me the object, for which one of the properties is equal to "Button". Give me is name.

So that I can, using JS, change its position, size, and so on.

---

Full JSON

```
{  
   "PG":{  
  "v":5,
  "h":20480,
  "w":25600,
  "pc":"FFFFFF",
  "de":"",
  "st":0,
  "Act":[  

  ],
  "S":[  
     {  
        "Y":"h",
        "b":1,
        "nm":"BUTTON1",
        "f":"1,0,1,0",
        "c":"FFFFFF,000000",
        "l":"2020,1840,4140,8820",
        "n":"Helvetica",
        "h":192,
        "L":0,
        "i":0,
        "j":1,
        "vj":1,
        "t":"Button",
        "Act":[  
           {  
              "e":"OnClick",
              "s":"\r\ngraphicReplace(\"Public/essai/vue0\");"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

}
}

Comment: It looks like it's `S[0].t`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON holds an *array* which in turn contains the rest of the *keys*. You can see that after the `'S'` key, brackets `[]` follow indicating just that.

So you(probably) need to use  `..S[0].t`

You can access arrays by their index like so `[0]` and keys with their 'names', like so `'.Act'`.

From what I see up there it should be `json.PG.S[0].t` where `json` means the name of the variable that actually contains that JSON,

```js
var json = {
  "PG": {
    "v": 5,
    "h": 20480,
    "w": 25600,
    "pc": "FFFFFF",
    "de": "",
    "st": 0,
    "Act": [

    ],
    "S": [{
      "Y": "h",
      "b": 1,
      "nm": "BUTTON1",
      "f": "1,0,1,0",
      "c": "FFFFFF,000000",
      "l": "2020,1840,4140,8820",
      "n": "Helvetica",
      "h": 192,
      "L": 0,
      "i": 0,
      "j": 1,
      "vj": 1,
      "t": "Button",
      "Act": [{
        "e": "OnClick",
        "s": "\r\ngraphicReplace(\"Public/essai/vue0\");"
      }]
    }]
  }
}


alert(json.PG.S[0].t);
```

e.g assuming:

```
var json = {  
   "PG":{  
  "v":5,
  "h":20480,
  "w":25600,
  "pc":"FFFFFF",
  "de":"",
  "st":0,
  "Act":[  

  ],
  "S":[  
     {  
        "Y":"h",
        "b":1,
        "nm":"BUTTON1",
        "f":"1,0,1,0",
        "c":"FFFFFF,000000",
        "l":"2020,1840,4140,8820",
        "n":"Helvetica",
        "h":192,
        "L":0,
        "i":0,
        "j":1,
        "vj":1,
        "t":"Button",
        "Act":[  
           {  
              "e":"OnClick",
              "s":"\r\ngraphicReplace(\"Public/essai/vue0\");"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
} }
```

Comment: It's correct, but doesn't seem to be the case. `S is not defined` anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed, I have tried this, and the result is inconclusive

alert(S[0].t)
VM2035:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: S is not defined

Comment: that's because you posted an incomplete JSON to begin with

Comment: I did not think it was necessary to have the whole thing. I'll edit my first post to attach it all.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, I do not know the name of the JSON variable, with turns my original question in "How can I find the json variable name?"

Comment: you don't, it's you who will assign it - assuming it comes as a response from somewhere - so take that response and do `var myJson=JSON.parse(response);` - then use `myJson` as the name of the variable to access it like so - `myJson.PG.S[0].t` - JSON's come as strings from a server/AJAX call etc - you need to parse it to make it an object again.

Comment: Isn't it to late at this point?
The CMS has done its job, the JSON file has been displayed in a canvas. I would like to change to position of objects in this canvas. If I reparse the JSON, how can the page know I refer to the objects already created?

Comment: too late for what? The server sends strings, you can only manipulate objects - `JSON.parse()` turns a json-valid string into an object. On the other-hand I have no idea what your CMS does or how to achieve the secondary purpose you just now stated:) No offence but it would be very hard for you to manipulate/built-on-top a CMS if you don't know the basics of HTML/JS, especially since your CMS requires you to manipulate JSON's

Answer (score 0):

you `Json` should be like

```
var S = [
     {
         "Y": "h",
         "b": 1,
         "nm": "BUTTON1",
         "f": "1,0,1,0",
         "c": "FFFFFF,000000",
         "l": "2020,1840,4140,8820",
         "n": "Helvetica",
         "h": 192,
         "L": 0,
         "i": 0,
         "j": 1,
         "vj": 1,
         "t": "Button",
         "Act": [
            {
                "e": "OnClick",
                "s": "\r\ngraphicReplace(\"Public/essai/vue0\");"
            }
         ]
     }
]
```

**or**

```
var obj = {
    "S": [
         {
             "Y": "h",
             "b": 1,
             "nm": "BUTTON1",
             "f": "1,0,1,0",
             "c": "FFFFFF,000000",
             "l": "2020,1840,4140,8820",
             "n": "Helvetica",
             "h": 192,
             "L": 0,
             "i": 0,
             "j": 1,
             "vj": 1,
             "t": "Button",
             "Act": [
                {
                    "e": "OnClick",
                    "s": "\r\ngraphicReplace(\"Public/essai/vue0\");"
                }
             ]
         }
    ]
}  
alert(S[0].t);  // if you choose first
alert(obj.S[0].t);  // if you choose second
```

Comment: It's being returned like that by a CMS  - I think he has trouble assigning it to a variable or something like that

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not make the JSON. It is created by the GUI, and read by the CMS. The very first character of it is a `{`, without any notion of variable :(

Comment: @MaximeVisconte did you actually `JSON.parse()`'d it first? - You have to parse it and assign it to a variable to access it properly

Comment: @Maxime Visconte assign it to some variable say `var obj` now `alert(obj.S[0].t)`

Comment: I assume the CMS does it, since the object described in the document is displayed on the screen. Is that a bad assumption?